# Local Notification is displayed without didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Tags: cocoa

I have quite an understanding issue with displaying local notifications.
As far as I was reading in other threads, one has first create and schedule the local notification with the application.

For displaying that notification, one has to use the delegates didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (if app is in background operation) and didReceiveLocalNotification: (if app is in foreground).

Now even though I did NOT change the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method, the notification is already getting viewed when my app is in the background.

It wouldn't be that big of a problem if the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: would at least be used when I specify it at all. But it doesn't.

So my problem is, that even though I haven't used the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method, the notification is getting displayed. When the user clicks on the notification, the app gets to foreground and the didReceiveLocalNotification: method is triggered and the notification is displayed again.

What I originally wanted to do is to cancelAllLocalNotifications on execution of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, but since it is not getting executed, I'm kinda stuck here.

Ok, there might be a workaround with applicationWillEnterForeground: but honestly, I'd like to understand, why the notification is getting displayed even without having specified that in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:.

All of your help is really appreaciated!! Thanks!!

```
//
//  myNotificationsClass.m
//


#import "myNotificationsClass.h"

@implementation myNotificationsClass

//Sets up a Local Notification with Message, TimeFromNow, BadgeNumber and UserInfo

//no Class Instance for calling this method needed!!

+ (void)setupLocalNotificationsWithMessage: (NSString *) message andTimeFromNow: (NSTimeInterval) seconds andAlertAction: (NSString *) alertAction andBadgeNumber: (NSInteger) badgeNumber andUserInfo: (NSDictionary *) infoDict {

//[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

// create date/time information
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:seconds];
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

//setup Appearence and Message
localNotification.alertBody = message; //@"Time to get up!";
localNotification.alertAction = alertAction;
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeNumber;

localNotification.userInfo = infoDict;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}

@end


//overwrites the viewWillAppear: Method from the primary Class to display a Test Notification

@implementation UIViewController (localNotification)
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [myNotificationsClass setupLocalNotificationsWithMessage:@"First Test after 2 Seconds" andTimeFromNow:2 andAlertAction:@"GoTo iSnah" andBadgeNumber:7 andUserInfo:nil];

}
@end

//receive Local Notifications even if the App is in Foreground
//overwrites the primery method
@implementation UIResponder (localNotificationForeground)

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]   objectForKey:@"CFBundleName"]
                                                        message:notification.alertBody
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alertView show];

    //reset Badge
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    


    //Because I don't want the Notification to be displayed twice 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    if (notification) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]   objectForKey:@"CFBundleName"]
                                                            message:notification.alertBody
                                                            delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];


        [alertView show];

        //reset Badge
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    }


    return YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are very close.  If the app is running in the background, the user responding to the notification will not cause the app to "launch".  "Launch" means the app is not running at all (foreground or background).  So only put code in there that you want to execute when the app launches or starts as a result of the user responding to your local notification.

So what you need for your didReceiveLocalNotification method is something to check the application state to see if it was in the foreground or in the background when the user responded to the local notification.

You might do something like the following to differentiate your logic between foreground and background:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:    (UILocalNotification *)notification
if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive ){
    NSLog(@"Was already in the foreground");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Was in the background");
}
```

}

Minor point, however.  Documentation states that the didReceiveLocalNotification method is invoked after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (if that method is implemented).  So if you have both methods implemented you'll need to make sure the combination of the 2 work correctly in a "launch" situation.